# Unexpected JSON response from sandbox

Tags: apex, query, json, remote-action

We were developing in a dev org and the json response is fine

Any idea to cause this error?

## Expected format `list of sobject`

```
          [
                      {
                        "Name": "Planned Payment Dates 2017",
                        "Id": "00P41000007XUEEEA4"
                      },
                      {
                        "Name": "Financing proposal",
                        "Id": "00P41000007XUDpEAO"
                      }
          ]
```

## UnExpecting format `list of sobject inside an strange object`

```
          [
          {
                        "s": 3,
                        "v": [
                          {
                            "s": 4,
                            "v": {
                              "Company_Name__c": "Test Borrower",
                              "Remaining_Time__c": "10",
                              "loan__Remaining_Investment_Amount__c": 10000.00,
                              "loan__Certificate_Rate__c": 2.000,
                              "loan__Income_Reinvested__c": 0.00,
                              "Id": "a1T4E000000Hd6YUAS"
                            }
                          }
          }
          ]
```

Comment: You should use wrapper class list if you're returning  list of sObject. Those properties looks weird, maybe if we can see some code it would be easier for us to recommend something.

Comment: Also your json is not formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not getting proper json formatted data. It should be something like this.

```
   [
      {
                    "s": 3,
                    "v": [
                      {
                        "s": 4,
                        "v": {
                          "Company_Name__c": "Test Borrower",
                          "Remaining_Time__c": "10",
                          "loan__Remaining_Investment_Amount__c": 10000.00,
                          "loan__Certificate_Rate__c": 2.000,
                          "loan__Income_Reinvested__c": 0.00,
                          "Id": "a1T4E000000Hd6YUAS"
                        }
                      }
                   ]
      }
      ]
```